Error when I'm trying to achieve a continuous migration process with Entity Framework in a Dockerized environment
I have the dockerfile for my API application, and I've an API with SQL Server as the database. Now I've also the migration file created by EntityMigration through Visual Studio. Now I want to add those migration file as startup for database container. Also I want to integrate the future migration if needed though migration file. My problem is the Dockerfile can't run the API container after build process. My API container is exited immediately after the building the dockerfile.
Right now, I am getting this error:

2024-07-02 13:06:00 exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

My Dockerfile for the API is
# Use the SDK image to build the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PaymentAPI/PaymentAPI.csproj", "PaymentAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PaymentAPI/PaymentAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PaymentAPI"
RUN dotnet build "PaymentAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "PaymentAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy the entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh .

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

# Start the application
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

The docker-compose.yml file is:
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - mssqldata:/var/opt/mssql

  paymentapi:
    build:
      context: ./PaymentAPI
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DevConnection=Server=mssql;Database=PaymentDetailDB;User=sa;Password=YourStrong!Passw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
    depends_on:
      - mssql

  paymentapp:
    build:
      context: ./PaymentApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8044:80"
    depends_on:
      - paymentapi

volumes:
  mssqldata:


The entrypoint.sh file is:
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Wait for SQL Server to be available
echo "Waiting for SQL Server to be available..."
until dotnet ef database update --context PaymentDetailContext; do
  >&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up..."
  sleep 1
done

# Start the application
exec dotnet PaymentAPI.dll

I want to start all three container, with the database initialization and future migration option enable. How can I achieve this or why I'm facing this error even if I place the entrypoint.sh file in the correct directory.

Is this really correct? COPY entrypoint.sh .

Have you checked to make sure that your entrypoint.sh file is saved using LF line endings? You could get errors similar to that if it's using CRLF line endings because it will use the shebang line to look for /bin/sh<cr>.

Yes I think, is this line makes the problem for getting the error?

If you're using VS Code then, with entrypoint.sh open in the current tab, you can try Ctrl+Shift+P and choose Change End of Line Sequence to choose between LF (linefeeds only, *nix style) or CRLF (carriage return-linefeed pairs, Windows style). Then save the change and rebuild your container.

Yes, It was CRLF before, now I changed to LF. But my problem still exist,
paymentapi-1  | exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
paymentapi-1 exited with code 1
@AlwaysLearning

Sorry, for the previous comment. You are right. @AlwaysLearning.
Right now my API container is running, but I can't access my API. I need to figure it out.
